# How to Fix ._changeCaps.dll is missing

Tags: windows, laptop

I'm trying to install some important software of Adobe related to my work on my laptop but whenever I try to run it an error pops up saying:

> ._changeCaps.dll is missing.

I do not know what it is saying missing although my laptop is quite new which I bought recently.

Comment: i found solution to fix [dll file missing problem](https://windowsmaximizer.com/files/dll/changecaps-dll) here if anyone will be facing same issue like me i hope it will help someone. thanks

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.